# Xamarin Visual Studio Android Designer wont Display

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I'm trying to do some Android C# app development for the first time. Iv installed Xamarin for VS2015 and I'm able to create, build, and start an Android Xamarin Project. The only problem is when I add an Android Layout, I can see the .axml source, but not the design view. No matter how many times I click on it, it keeps the source view open. This is quite confusing and aggravating as there are no errors or warnings being displayed. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is a GIF of me trying to click on the Designer tab profusely:
[image: VS2015XamarinTroubles]

Answer (score 1):

```
In your Solution Explorer, right click on an axml file and select "Open With". As one of the options, you should see "Android Designer". Open it with that. In addition, you can reset it as the Default by clicking the "Set As Default" button.
```

asp below link:
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/5233/visual-studio-plugin-cant-switch-between-source-design-anymore

Comment: I don't get the opinion 'Android designer' within Open With. 'Mobile development with .Net' is installed in the Visual Studio Installer, and I have Xamarin UI options available, but the designer is not available.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I instead opened main.axml in the layout folder which allowed it to load in some files for a few seconds and showed the designer.